# Contraction mapping theorem with respect to the supremum norm.

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis

Question:

For continuous $f$ on the interval $[0,1]$, let $(Tf)(x) = x + \lambda \int_0^x (x-t)f(t)$.

Find the range of values of $\lambda$ for which the transformation $T$ is a contraction with respect to the supremum norm on $C([0,1])$.

Where I get stuck.

$|(Tf)(x) - (Tg)(x)| \leq|\lambda| ||f-g||_\infty \int_0^x|x-t|dt$

I don't know what to do with the integral. Any hints or tips?

Comment: Why not actually calculate the integral? Then remember that $0 \leq x \leq 1$.

Comment: $\int_0^x|x-t|dt\leq \int_0^1|x-t|dt\leq \cdots$

Answer (score 1):

Since $x\in[0,1]$ you can say: $\int_{0}^x|x-t|dt\leq \int_{0}^1|x-t|dt\leq \int_{0}^1 1+|t|dt$ because $|x-t|$ is a positive function. Here the important thing is this integral is bounded.